# Map with different types to String

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to learn some functional programming in Scala.

I have this Map:

```
val params: Map[String, QueryMap] = Map(
  "a" -> SimpleQueryVal("1"),
  "b" -> ComplexQueryVal("2", "3")
)
```

Where QueryMap is (might not be the best approach):

```
sealed trait QueryMap
case class SimpleQueryVal(value: String) extends QueryMap
case class ComplexQueryVal(values: String*) extends QueryMap
```

My result would be having a string like query parameters: ?a=1&b=2&b=3

I tried something, but my method return an Iterator[String] even I use mkString, looks ugly and I am sure that there's a very simple way of doing it.

```
def paramString(queryMap: Map[String, QueryMap]) = queryMap.keys.map { key =>
  val params = queryMap(key) match {
    case SimpleQueryVal(x) => "%s=%s".format(key, x)
    case complexQuery: ComplexQueryVal => complexQuery.values.map { value =>
      "%s=%s".format(key, value)
    }
  }
  val result: String = params match {
    case s: String => s + "&"
    case s: ArrayBuffer[_] => s.mkString("&")
  }
  result.mkString
}
```

I would appreciate any idea that would make me learn something for today. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the result `String` can be built in a simpler, more straight forward, manner.

```
def paramString(queryMap: Map[String, QueryMap]): String = queryMap.map{
  case (k, sq: SimpleQueryVal) => s"$k=${sq.value}"
  case (k, cq: ComplexQueryVal)=> cq.values.map(k + "=" + _).mkString("&")
}.mkString("&")
```

Answer (score 3):

A little cleaner:

```
def paramString(queryMap: Map[String, QueryMap]) = queryMap.flatMap {
  case (key, SimpleQueryVal(x)) => Seq(s"$key=$x")
  case (key, ComplexQueryVal(values @ _*)) => values.map {v =>
    s"$key=$v"
  }
}.mkString("&")
```

No need for `ArrayBuffer` or to repeat the `.mkString("&")`.

Keep in mind that this is good for just learning. If you're actually trying to handle HTTP query string parameters, you need to `URLEncode` the keys and the values and there's probably better libraries for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def paramString(queryMap: Map[String, QueryMap]) = {
  val qParams = queryMap.keys.map { key =>
    queryMap(key) match {
      case SimpleQueryVal(x) => "%s=%s".format(key, x)
      case complexQuery: ComplexQueryVal => complexQuery.values.map { value =>
        "%s=%s".format(key, value)
      }.mkString("&")
    }
  }
  qParams.mkString("&")
}

println(paramString(params))
```

Here, first you get a `Set[String]` like `a=1` or `b=2&b=3`. Then you simply do another `.mkString("&")` to concatenate them all.